# Relocating Torrent Files and Downloads

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Ok, so I recently moved all my .torrent files and the associated downloads into a different folder. For some reason, uTorrent (Mac) can't find the downloaded file, and begins downloading it anew. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Right-click (*giggle*) the torrent, select

- Advanced
- Set download location...
- pick the location where the loaded files are now at
- Click OK

[image]

After you've selected the new download location, force uTorrent to check it by clicking:

- Advanced
- Force re-check

Comment: +1. You might then need to run a "Force Re-Check" (the option above Advanced).

Comment: Oh, yes, you definitely will have to run "Force re-check" after that. i'll add that.

Comment: Apparently, the "Advanced" options don't exist in the Mac version. Oh well, I'll accept this answer when they add it in.

Comment: @waiwai933: That's why i "*giggled*" at the step where you have to Right-click.  :)